# How can you recursively construct a list inside of a singular Some trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming

I am going through the red book 'Functional Programming in Scala' right now so at the same time I am learning Scala. If I understand correctly, trait does not mean object. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

My issue is that I do not know how to construct a list of type A while having it wrapped inside of a `Some` trait. I would appreciate hints in the right direction.

In the exercise I am doing, I am asked to define a function that is meant to transform every element in the list and then have the entire list inside of a `Some` trait.

here is my code:

```
def traverse[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => Option[B]): Option[List[B]] = a match {
    case Nil => Nil: B
    case h :: t => f(h) flatMap ( hh => hh :: traverse(t)(f))
  }
```

I feel like I'm on the right tracks here, but the scala interpreter complains that `::` is not available to `Option[List[B]]`. I think this is because the type signature of the function doesn't return a list, it returns a List wrapped within a Some.

But could my intution about **flatMap** also be wrong? `f(h)` returns an `Option[B]`. Calling flatmap actually looks inside of the Option so hh is of type `B` correct? My logic is that this way I can construct a list of type B with the function `hh :: traverse(t)(f)`. But I am not completely sure about being right here.

If it makes any difference, I am using the scala interpreter with the :paste command. I am not sure if this is making things buggier.

Comment: `traverse` returns you e.g. `Some(list)`, you want to add your `hh` to that list, not to `Some`. You normally do it with `map`: `Some(list).map(hh::_)`, which will return you `Some(hh::list)`.

Comment: Why did I not think of that!... I was close atleast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, trait does not mean object.

Traits are traits, objects are objects. Traits are somewhat like "interfaces" in Java, and `object`s are singleton objects. Those singleton objects can extend from traits.

> `Some` trait

`Some` is not a trait, it's a [class extending `Option`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Some.html).

> it returns a List wrapped within a Some.

It returns a list wrapped inside `Option` (i.e., it can be `None`, without any list at all). In order to call `::` on the optional list value, you need another `map`:

```
def traverse[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => Option[B])
: Option[List[B]] = a match {
  case Nil => Some(Nil)
  case h :: t => f(h) flatMap {
    hValue => traverse(t)(f) map {
      tValue => hValue :: tValue
    }
  }
}
```

which you could abbreviate as:

```
def traverse[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => Option[B])
: Option[List[B]] = a match {
  case Nil => Some(Nil)
  case h :: t => f(h) flatMap {
    hValue => traverse(t)(f) map (hValue :: _)
  }
}
```

or just use a `for`-comprehension right away:

```
def traverse[A, B](a: List[A])(f: A => Option[B])
: Option[List[B]] = a match {
  case Nil => Some(Nil)
  case h :: t => for {
    hValue <- f(h)
    tValue <- traverse(t)(f)
  } yield (hValue :: tValue)
}
```

Comment: Was my logic correct atleast? That because the type signature of the function was that of a `Option[List[A]]` it wouldn't compile? So that is why, the map needs to be used in order to actually have the types match. 

Also, was I correct about flatMap?

Comment: Do you think I am cheating by asking questions here? I figure the authors of this book intend for you to struggle so you develop the intuition for things on your own... (I'm assuming you read this book)

Comment: @DanielLockHart You were just missing the `map` to get from the incorrect `hh :: traverse(t)(f)` to `traverse(t)(f) map (hh :: _)`, the rest seems more or less correct. No, I don't think it's "cheating" - after I read the book, I started seeing the applicatives and traversables everywhere, so I guess I got enough exercise by actually solving my current problems using those techniques (admittedly, when I read the book, those ideas weren't exactly new to me already, so I didn't care to solve all the exercises).

Comment: @DanielLockHart In case you want to have a "replacement exercise": redo the same exercise without using `flatMap`, use `zip` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more about monadic operations. `Option` is a monad, but it might be easier to consider it as a container with zero or one value. Something like `List()` which has no elements, or `List(x)` which has exactly one element. To modify an element hidden inside your container you need `map`:

```
List(1).map(_ + 1) => List(2)
Some(1).map(_ + 1) => Some(2)
```

But `map` can't change the number of elements in a list. So what you need is another operation, which is called `flatMap`, which takes a function which in turn takes an element and returns a `List`:

```
List(1).flatMap { x => List() } => List()
Some(1).flatMap { x => None } => None

List(1).flatMap { x => List(x + 1) } => List(2)
Some(1).flatMap { x => Some(x + 1) } => Some(2)
```

This will propagate a "failure", which is an empty list, as `List().flatMap { ...whatever...}` will always return an empty list.

`traverse` is doing just that, propagating "failure" if your function `f` for any element returns `None` (i.e. `List()` in my interpretation) and combining non-failure results into a new list inside container. Since what you get from `traverse` is a container with list inside, you need to apply `map`. And because "failure" if it happens should be propagated, you need `flatMap`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that the fact that `Option` is a monad is not really required here: `Option.apply`, `zip` and `map` would be sufficient, because it's enough to be `Applicative` in order to be able to traverse traversables, `flatMap` is actually overkill.